Apache Ignite Custom SQL function with Expression as a parameter
I'm looking for a possible way how to create such a function:
SELECT id, MYFUN(value ORDER BY time) FROM People GROUP BY id.

But when I run such a query it returns error that says:
Failed to parse query. ORDER BY unexpected

I've tried different parmeters for my custom function but I can't pass such a expression. If I do pass just column MYFUN(value) or MYFUN(SUM(value)) it works fine.
Do we have any way how to accept such an expression? May be there are some predefined parameters, like Row, Contex etc...

It's not currently possible to define a custom aggregate function. You don't say what your function does, but maybe it's possible to rewrite your SQL to use a scalar function. Alternatively, you may have to consider writing your query as a compute task.

I would also add that ORDER BY is a statement wide operation such as:
SELECT id, MYFUNC(value) AS MYFUNC_VALUE FROM People GROUP BY id ORDER BY MYFUNC_VALUE
Other issues that I see with your question are "GROUP BY id"
If id is distinct then you will have groups of 1 and as such there is no
need for a group by clause. Group by is used to group multiple elements in a result set that have the same value such as grouping all people that have the same job or are the same sex, ...
Hope that helps.
